# Unable to retrieve data, mysql php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an issue, i cannot get any results from mysql on a production box but can on a development box, we use PHP 5.3 with MySQL (pdo).

```
$sd = $this->dbh->quote($sd);
$si_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_wl_data 
           WHERE (site_domain = $sd OR siteDomainMasked = $sd);";
if($this->dbh->query($si_sql)->rowCount() > 0) {
    //gets to here, just doesnt get through the loop
    $sql = "SELECT pk_aid, site_name, site_css, site_img_sw, supportPhone FROM tbl_wl_data
            WHERE (site_domain = $sd OR siteDomainMasked = $sd);";
    foreach($this->dbh->query($sql) as $wlsd) { //-- fails here
        if($wlsd['wl_status'] != '1') {
            require "_domainDisabled.php";
            exit;
        }
        $this->pk_aid = $wlsd['pk_aid'];
        $this->siteTitle = $wlsd['site_name'];
        $this->siteCSS = $wlsd['site_css'];
        $this->siteImage = $wlsd['site_img_sw'];
        $this->siteSupportPhone = $wlsd['supportPhone'];
    }
} else {
    throw new ERR_SITE_NOT_LINKED;
}
```

It just doesnt seem to get into the loopk, i ran the query in navicat and it returns the data.

Really confused :S

Comment: What goes wrong at which point exactly? Do you output your [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)? What is the row count?

Comment: @Pekka:  foreach($this->dbh->query($sql) as $wlsd) {

Comment: At least `$sd = $this->dbh->quote($sd);` is completely useless here.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel: as we are not using prepared statments etc, we use that.

Comment: I see that you're using that. Unfortunately, it is completely useless here. It heps nothing. To make it do any good, you have to enclose your variable in quotes. And why don't you use prepared statements while using PDO is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
$si_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_wl_data WHERE (site_domain = $sd OR siteDomainMasked = $sd);";
if ($this->dbh->query($si_sql)->rowCount() > 0) ...
```

Will always evaluate to TRUE even if the there are no content in your table. In fact, it will always return a single row named `COUNT(*)` that contains the number of rows matching your WHERE clause.

You should scrap the first `if` and do that instead:

```
$si_sql = "SELECT pk_aid, site_name, site_css, site_img_sw, supportPhone FROM tbl_wl_data WHERE (site_domain = $sd OR siteDomainMasked = $sd);";
if ($this->dbh->query($si_sql)->rowCount() > 0) {
    // foreach here
}
```

Comment: @Kyle: it probably means that you're table is empty or your query is invalid. If you var_dump `rowCount()` you will probably have 0 there.

Comment: @Netcoder: var_dump($this->dbh->query($si_sql)->rowCount()); returns int(1)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, another developer was truncating and then adding data all the time. I have sorted it...